# Grouping dataframe by occurances of specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to anaylse some logs of drone flights in Pandas. The logs have a timestamp, the message that the drone sent and some sensory data. Every couple of messages a position is sent. I now want to group all rows in order before a position message (or in other words just split the whole dataframe into groups every time a position message occurs). Those messages don't necessarily occur in a set frequency.

Here a simplified example:

This

```
id  timestamp       message  additional_sensor_value
 1   12:10:44         speed                      144     
 2   12:10:46      position                       23
 3   12:10:63   orientation                      222
 4   12:10:82        status                        2
 5   12:11:02      position                       63
 6   12:11:24         speed                       52  
 7   12:11:43      position                      127
```

should be grouped something like this:

```
id  timestamp       message  additional_sensor_value
12:10:46
 1   12:10:44         speed                      144     
 2   12:10:46      position                       23

12:11:02
 3   12:10:63   orientation                      222
 4   12:10:82        status                        2
 5   12:11:02      position                       63

12:11:43
 6   12:11:24         speed                       52  
 7   12:11:43      position                      127
```

the goal is to get the average of the additional_sensor_value for each occurrence of position to get a scatter plot of all logged data, not just the position data like I have it right now in my example below.

[image: scatter plot of drone flight]

If you have any other suggestions how to solve this problem in a better way I'd be happy to hear them, but I try to avoid using for loops, since those dataframes can be very large (>1 mil. rows) and I want to keep it as quick as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create helper `Series` by compare `message` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then change order by indexing `[::-1]` and create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), last change order to original:

```
g = df['message'].eq('position').iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]

for _, x in df.groupby(g, sort=False):
    print (x['timestamp'].iat[-1])
    print (x)
12:10:46
   id timestamp   message  additional_sensor_value
0   1  12:10:44     speed                      144
1   2  12:10:46  position                       23
12:11:02
   id timestamp      message  additional_sensor_value
2   3  12:10:63  orientation                      222
3   4  12:10:82       status                        2
4   5  12:11:02     position                       63
12:11:43
   id timestamp   message  additional_sensor_value
5   6  12:11:24     speed                       52
6   7  12:11:43  position                      127
```

If need aggregate use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `g` like:

```
g = df['message'].eq('position').iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
df = df.groupby(g, sort=False).agg(avg=('additional_sensor_value', 'mean'),
                                   time = ('timestamp','last'))
print (df)
               avg      time
message                     
3        83.500000  12:10:46
2        95.666667  12:11:02
1        89.500000  12:11:43
```

Comment: Nice one. In order to preserve the order you can add an `.iloc[::-1]` to g as following:
`df['message'].eq('position').iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1].iloc[::-1]`
So you can avoid `sort` within the `groupby`

Comment: Wow, dissecting this to actually get whats happening will take some time I think, but it works perfectly, thank you very much! :D
(also this post put my reputation to a point so I can upvote, so full success! :D)